# How do I force HTTPS on a some pages? (PHP)

Tags: php, ssl

I have a single PHP file which handles credit card processing. It starts as a form to input the credit card number, then becomes a "confirm" screen (showing the credit card number) then once more to process and display the results. All three loads will be done with PHP submits (I realize the confirm might be better as Javascript, but I didn't write it). It is the only file in the directory which handles credit cards, and therefore it is the only one which needs httpS connection.

I have tried forcing this with the $_SERVER array, looking up the protocol used to connect from the prefix of the SCRIPT_URI (or other entry), but none had the prefix.

Is there a simple way to do this...i want ssl on 5 pages homepage, login, register, contact page and if user visit other page then he should be on non ssl version

Sorry for the questions, but my searches thus far here haven't uncovered a working solution, and I'm afraid I don't know what the best practice is.

Comment: "therefore it is the only one which needs httpS connection" — Just shove the entire site though SSL. It's simpler, it protects data that your users might care about even if you don't, and it gives you better SEO.

Comment: Apart from the true thing mentioned by @quentin you should take a look at the http servers rewriting capabilities, for example `mod_rewrite` for the apache http server. It allows you to redirect single or multiple requests for example to switch between protocol schemes.

Comment: Please (*please!*) if you're handing credit card numbers, you need to be absolutely certain that you are complying with the PCI regulations. There are very strict rules about what you do with. HTTPS is just a small part of those regulations. You need to be certain that your software, your server and your processes are PCI compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code on php pages you want:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate $_SERVER['HTTPS']. This will have a non empty value if https is used and an empty value otherwise.

If you detect a non https connection you can redirect the user, e.g. using php header() method.

Another way to achieve this would be to use .htaccess configuration (if you're running on apache web server):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^creditcard\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Using https for the whole website is a really good option, too.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to redirect 4 specific pages to https,

- page1.php
- page2.php
- page3.php
- page4.php

then you would do something like this:

Create a *.htaccess* file in your root directory and add the following lines to it.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php|page3\.php|page4\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```